# unix automatically set different rights for files and subfolders

Tags: linux, unix

i have the folder with rights 700.
and want make new subfolders with automatically set rights 755
but files with rights 644

is that possible?

> somefolder (700)
>   |-- subfolder1 (755)
>   |-- subfolder2 (755)
>   |-- file 1 (644)
>   |-- file 2 (644)

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with `umask`. Umask value is used that way:

- directories are created using 777 & !umask
- files are created using 666 & !umask (no `x` for ordinary files)

As :

- 755 == 777 & !022
- 644 == 666 & !011

You then have to set `umask 022` when creating directories and `umask 011` when creating files.